# Can the effects of Alter Self and Disguise Self be combined to make you look like a specific person?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, disguise

Related to the question on whether or not [*alter self* was a better version of *disguise self*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45758/is-alter-self-strictly-better-than-disguise-self-as-at-will-invocations), I know [*alter self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alter-self) affects only the body, but not of the character's possessions, while [*disguise self*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self) affects the possessions and clothing.

**Could you combine the effects of both spells in order to gain the benefit of sounding like a specific target and seemingly being dressed in their attire?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Yes.

*Alter self:* Change Appearance. You transform your appearance. You decide what you look like, including your height, weight, facial features, **sound of your voice**, hair length, coloration, and distinguishing characteristics, if any.

Moreover, only *alter self* requires concentration, so that is not an issue either.

Comment: You might add that a Charisma (Performance) check might still be needed to *act* like the person being imitated.

Comment: @Marq Sounds reasonable, feel free to edit that in

Comment: Performance?  Maybe for some things (like if you were imitating a bard or were far enough way), but when closely interacting I think Charisma (Deception) will usually be more appropriate.